# Can NgElse reference an imported component?

Tags: angular

So I'm trying to make a generic loading icon for my site. This is what I've got so far.

```
  <div>
    <p *ngIf="questionsLoaded; else loadingSign" > {{lstQuestions?.length}} question/s found </p>
    <ng-template #loadingSign><app-loading></app-loading>></ng-template>
  </div>
```

Then in my component, I have a boolean value name questionsLoaded that is initially set to false, but then is set to true after the data arrives. Something like this...

```
this.serverService.getQuestions(topicId, questionStatus).subscribe
      (
      data => {
        this.lstQuestions = data;
        this.questionsLoaded = true;
      },
```

I have a component called LoadingComponent (which is what app-loading loads) which is where I want to create my generic loading sign. At the moment, it's basically just a view that has this

```
<p>
  loading right now!
</p>
```

This all works. However, I want my code to be cleaner. My question is about the ngElse. From what I've read, it seems I can use ngElse to reference a ng-template.

Does that ng-template have to be defined on the component or can it be somehow imported into the component?

So instead of

```
  <div>
    <p *ngIf="questionsLoaded; else loadingSign" > {{lstQuestions?.length}} question/s found </p>
    <ng-template #loadingSign><app-loading></app-loading></ng-template>
  </div>
```

Is it possible to have it like this where the app-loading is an imported component?

```
  <div>
    <p *ngIf="questionsLoaded; else app-loading" > {{lstQuestions?.length}} question/s found </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Instead of an  imported component you can provide it as an input from parent in the form of TemplateRef.

Comment: @AnkitKapoor - can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible.

According to this article: https://medium.com/aviabird/ngif-else-lands-in-angular-2-0-a242940e54ff

> By default, else template is null, unless specified by a local
>   reference to an HTML element.

A local reference, so your imported component is not a local reference.

And after reading the documentation: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf they always use `ng-template`